# How to exclude rows with varchar2 value that is not null, but exports as null

Tags: null, export, oracle12c, varchar2

I have some data, which I cannot change, in a `varchar2(800)` column, which displays in SQL Developer as a `null` and exports from there as a `null`, but is not `null`.

Here's what I tried:

- `length(mycol)` return `3`
- `asciistr(mycol)` returns `null`
- `substr(mycol, 1, 1)` returns `null` (the other positions return normal letters)
- `ascii(substr(mycol, 1, 1))` returns `180`, which is a [*acute accent*](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b4/index.htm)

I want to *not* select rows that will export with a `null` value.

How can I do that?

I tried `asciistr(mycol) is not null`, but that also filters out text with accented characters that do not export as `null`. I want to export accented characters, but not when the whole column will be exported as `null`.

`mycol is not null` and `to_char(mycol) is not null` had no effect.

Obviously, I need a solution that will work for any length of input and character weirdness at any position in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Acute accent's ASCII code is 239. Have a look at this example; see if it helps.

Insert some values into a table; one of these is the *acute accent*:

```
SQL> create table test (mycol varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('a');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test values (chr(239));

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

MYCOL
----------
a
´
```

What's stored in there? Pay attention to the **DUMP** function:

```
SQL> select mycol, dump(mycol) dmp, ascii(mycol) ascii
  2  from test;

MYCOL      DMP                    ASCII
---------- -------------------- -------
a          Typ=1 Len=1: 97           97
´          Typ=1 Len=1: 239         239

SQL> select * from test
  2  where ascii(mycol) <> 239;

MYCOL
----------
a

SQL>
```

Check what `DUMP` returns in your case; maybe there's some more *garbage* in the column but - if you find out what it really is - you might even be able to `UPDATE` that column and put a "real" `NULL` (or something else) in there .

Comment: That’s all fine, but A) the character in question is 180, not 239, and B) character 180 was the only character I’ve found so far that has the problem and it may not always be in position 1, so any reference to a particular character or position is not a useful answer, and C) exactly how does `dump()` help me output the text value of the column?

Comment: A) Acute accent (https://theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/acute-accent-ascii-code-239.html); if it is 180, OK, doesn't really matter. B) Aha; so, string contains *acute accent* somewhere; it is not the only character in the column. C) DUMP won't help to *output* the result. I hoped that it might help finding what's really stored in that column. Oh well, sorry that I couldn't help. Good luck, by all means!